# Explaining Constant $\mathrm{corr}(\hat{y},y)$ in Ridge Regression as $\lambda$ Varies

Tags: regression, correlation, ridge-regression

I was recently asked the question, "In ridge regression $\hat{y}=X(X^\top X+\lambda I)^{-1} X^\top y$, why might the correlation $\mathrm{corr}(\hat{y},y)$ between the predicted values ($\hat{y}$) and actual values ($y$) remain constant as $\lambda$ varies?" My initial thought is that this could be due to the eigenvalues of the $X^\top X$ matrix being roughly equal. However, I'm not certain if this is the only factor at play or if there are other potential reasons for this phenomenon. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is $y$ a number or vector?  Besides, by "might be", you meant what you stated can be either true or false?

Comment: Thanks @Zhanxiong for asking and sorry for the confusion. $y$ is a vector and what I meant by this question was, if we observed that the correlation remains constant, what could be a possible cause? Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a ridge in the parameter space, that ridge is a set of values where the fit hardly changes anywhere along it (the $\hat{y}$ values are essentially the same along that ridge even though $\hat{\beta}$ changes).

It's $\hat{\beta}$ that's not well-determined if you don't regularize, while the fit is nearly fixed.

Since that's the exact case where you want to use ridge regression, a collection of more or less regularized fits (larger or smaller $\lambda$ values) will still end up very near to the top of that ridge, and so have almost the same fit -- i.e. almost the same $\hat{y}$ values.

Which is to say, when you really want to use ridge regression (because you have an ill-determined system leading to a ridge in log-likelihood - or in -SSE - in the beta-space), that's exactly when you should expect to see the fit hardly change as you change $\lambda$.

Since the fit is barely changing, the correlation is nearly constant.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b for your explanation. Just to clarify, are you saying that this situation occurs whenever the design matrix $X$ has multicollinearity?

Comment: That would generally be what would lead to the ridge here, yes,  and presumably why you're regularizing. Ridges in parameter space  can crop up in a variety of other contexts,  though, with similar effect - one might argue that even then, its at least a form of local multicollinearity.